# Изображения как ресурсы из другой сборки (с картинками!)

Tags: c#, wpf, assembly, xaml, изображения

Здравствуйте!

Пишу приложение на WPF и захотелось вынести все вспомогательные ресурсы в отдельную сборку (текстовые сообщения, надписи, картинки) для этого, естественно, создал в солюшене проект Class Library (пробовал и Custom Library - результат такой же), добавил папки Images и Resources, и соответственно, добавил в них картинки (формат png) и файлы ресурсов

[image: Картинка 1]

Далее добавил картинки в ресурсы

[Картинка 2 http://www.screencapture.ru/uploaded/a2/d4/45/a2d44551_thumb.jpg](http://www.screencapture.ru/uploaded/a2/d4/45/a2d44551_thumb.jpg)

Естественно, в других проектах указал ссылки на это сборку и дальше пытаюсь указать путь к картинке, как вот описывается вот **[Здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly)**

Самое, что интересное в дизайнере отображается как надо (картинку прекрасно видит)

[image: Картинка 3]

Когда компилирую и запускаю, то "сосачку" он мне выводит

[image: Картинка 4]

Скажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

**Ответ на свой вопрос**
Второе действие, как добавление картинок в ресурсы, можно не делать, вместо этого нужно в  в свойствах изображения Build Action выставить значение Resource - и тогда все нормально подгружаться будет 
[Откуда я это взял](http://blogs.vbcity.com/xtab/archive/2007/08/06/8575.aspx)

Comment: Ну, это к телепатам. Мало ли, где можно ошибиться. Может, в каталоге, откуда запускается приложение, нету assembly с ресурсами.

Comment: что вы имели ввиду, говоря о зависании, может я что-то неправильно понял? [Проблема с шаблонами в Entity Framework](http://hashcode.ru/questions/219109/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-entity-framework)

Comment: попробуйте заново добавить картинки, но не добавляйте их в ресурсы. там в свойствах изображений может что не так.

Comment: Ответ на свой вопрос лучше оформить именно ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Если студия руссифицирована, то попробуйте так:

В обозревателе решений выделяете картинки, в свойствах меняете значение параметра "действие при сборке" на "Resource". Все должно будет заработать, картинки встроятся в библиотеку. Если не поможет, то есть еще параметр "Копировать в выходной каталог".

Answer (score 1):

Добавление картинок в ресурсы не нужно. Вместо этого нужно в свойствах изображения *Build Action* выставить значение *Resource*.

---

<sub>Перенёс ответ из комментария.</sub>