# При запуске приложения не видно картинки внутри кнопки

Tags: wpf, xaml

Привет. Есть такой xaml код 
`

```
<Button x:Name="goBack"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" Height="50" FontSize="16" Cursor="Hand" Click="goBack_Click" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Img/back.png" Stretch="Uniform" Height="45" Width="50" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

`
В preview картинка отображается нормально, но при запуске ничего не видно и на клик, соответственно, не отвечает.
Почему? Вроде высоту и ширину везде указал.

Comment: картинка точно является ресурсом?

Comment: Вангую, неправильно выставили Build Action.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595470/Почему-не-отображаются-картинки-при-запуске-программы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/219975/10105

Comment: Спасибо. Но всё равно не работает. Создал папку resources, через Add → Existing Item добавил картинку, bulid action - Resource. Теперь ошибка file 'back.png' cannot be found.

Comment: Хотя в обозревателе решений всё есть и картинка открывается даже...

Comment: После перезагрузки ПК всё заработало...

Comment: Напишите ответ?